# Set up wireless in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: wireless

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a seperate drive. I can choose which drive to boot to in bios Ubuntu boots great. I am however, unable to set up my wireless connection. Could someone please help...

Comment: We need much more information about your computer. What manufacturer and model is it? Have you tried to install the drivers for the wireless?

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know enough about your computer(due to lack of info), but I would try to install drivers:

1. Connect your computer to the internet using an ethernet cable.
2. Click the top icon in the launcher to search for applications, and enter "Additional Drivers".
3. Wait for it to load, select the drivers for your system(there should be one or two choices), and click Activate below. Wait for it to finish, reboot, and attempt to connect again.